# two button on two different views calling the same function, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a SPA with two different views one for subjects and one for student, 
in subject view I have a save button in app/views/subject/subject.html:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="saveInfo()">
            Save
    </button>
```

I want to add the same function in the student views , saveInfo() pass the data into a service in the app factory which save the data in DB through fill_table.php.
the app factory in app/javascript/services.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {
var serviceBase = 'http://localhost/php/';
var obj = {};
document.title = "myApp on " + serviceBase;
obj.postData = function (user, data) {

return $http.post(serviceBase + 'fill_table.php', { "data": data, "user": {'username': user.name, 'password': user.password }).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
};
```

saveInfo() is in app/views/subject/subject.js:

```
    $scope.saveInfo = function() {
    console.log("saveInfo");
    $scope.loadingInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'modalLoading.html',
      size: "l",
    });

    return getChanges( $indexedDB, $q).then( function(responsesArray) {
        var jsonData = {};
        $scope.errorInstance = undefined;
        for (var i=0; i < DB_TABLES.length; i++) {
            var table = DB_TABLES[i];
            var items = responsesArray[i]
            if (items.length > 0){
                jsonData[table] = items;
            }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        return services.postData($scope.selectedUser, jsonData);


    })
   }
```

I want to add the mentioned button into  app/views/student/student.html. i tried and copied the code from the subject.js into Student but for some reason it does not work eventhough i checked everything was correct so is there a way to only that function from subject.js into Student.html

**note 1** getChanges() is another function get the inserted info and pass it into saveinfo().

**note 2**  right now I can save the info inserted student view by pressing save button in subject view

Comment: What is the specific problem adding this button? Also note that the file that some code is in is not as important as the component structure used ....controller vs view template

Comment: is there a short way to do instead of copying the functions from the subject.js into student.js

Comment: Can use services to share functions across app. Can also use directives for re-usable common functionality

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two html files and two controller (student and subject). To share data/functions between these, you could use a service or factory to handle all your http request. This is reusable and accessible from all your controllers.

```
app.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {

   var postStudent = function (student) {
        return $http.post("api/Student/Post", student);
   };

   var getChanges = function (){
       return $http.get("api/Student/Changes", student);
   };

   return {
       postStudent : postStudent, 
       getChanges : getChanges 
   };
}])
```

Now you can use can call the services from your controller as you see fit.

```
app.controller('StudentController', ['service', function(service){
  service.postStudent(student).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log('success');

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('error ' + response);

  });

  service.getChanges().then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log('success');

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('error ' + response);

  });
}]);


app.controller('SubjectController', ['service', function(service){
  service.postStudent(student).then(functionsuccessCallback(response){    
      }, 
      function errorCallback(response) {    
      });

  service.getChanges().then(function successCallback(response) {
      }, 
      function errorCallback(response) {
      });
  }]);
```

Note that the above has not been implemented, but should provide you with an outline.